# Вывод в tkinter и изменение изображение pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('505x520')

def func():
    x = int(ent1.get())
    y = int(ent2.get())
    img_pixels[x, y] = (255, 255, 255)
    
    tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((1000,1000)))
    canvas.itemconfigure(item_number, image = tk_img)

ent1 = tk.Entry()
ent1.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

ent2 = tk.Entry()
ent2.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

btn1 = tk.Button(command = func, text = 'Place')
btn1.grid(column = 2, row = 0)

canvas = tk.Canvas(width= 505, height= 520)
canvas.grid(column = 0, row = 1, columnspan = 3)

img = Image.new(mode='RGB', size=(20, 20))
tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img.resize((1000,1000)))
img_pixels = img.load()
item_number = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = tk_img)


root.mainloop()
```

Нужно чтобы когда пользователь вводил координаты пикселя на изображении и нажимал кнопку Place выбраный пиксель становился белым. Но вместо этого после нажатия кнопки изображение просто исчезает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно обновить изображение после изменения пикселя. Нужно добавить tk_img.paste(img.resize((1000,1000)))

```
def func():
    x = int(ent1.get())
    y = int(ent2.get())
    img_pixels[x, y] = (255, 255, 255)
    tk_img.paste(img.resize((1000, 1000)))
```